# Will there have to be a concerted effort to train new developers for legacy systems?

Tags: history, cobol

If we consider legacy systems that are still crucial to modern life, say for instance ATM infrastructure. If they have been coded with old languages like Cobol, for instance, would there have to be an effort to educate a new generation in there operations, or is there nothing that is keeping a good C# / Java developer from working with these systems if he / she is required to?

Assuming that eventually the OG nerds that originally developed and maintained these system, will eventually retire.

Comment: Many of them have already retired, and been brought back out of retirement ;-).

Comment: I realise that this question may be better suited to the CS.SE.

Comment: It's no so much the languages that are the problem but the coding styles and evenronments used. Teaching a developer a new language is easy. Teaching a developer to work in an environment without testing, scopes, structured calls or debuggers is much harder. And really these systems should be moved, if they still need to change.

Comment: @user1937198 The debugger on the AS/400 could do things that Java/C# programmers can just look in envy at.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RUMkqIpLy6M

Comment: They have retired\died and it's an increasing problem for the likes of banks, who have many batch processing systems in COBOL and the like, glued together over decades, often running on old hardware with no documentation.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen And I'm personally of the opinion that if you were writing code from scratch for an AS/400 with no legacy code to work with, you could get a system way better than a modern spark cluster or SAP system. Does depend on having a version of the system you can attach a debugger to though.

Comment: ...reference the old joke about the COBOL programmer who was woken up out of a long cryogenic sleep...in the year 9998.

Comment: @user1937198 Perhaps.   Voluntarily going vendor proprietary (and an expensive one at that) on a new project these days may not be a good long term strategic solution.  Also Java programs all ran in batch so _I_ couldn't rely on the debugger.

Comment: Yep, strategically and commercially it makes no sense, even if technically z/Architecture has a lot going for it compared to the mess that is modern x86.

Comment: @AlanB But it still runs.  Battle tested production code is quite valuable.

Comment: @NeilMeyer Your assumption that old is a bad thing does not necessarily hold.  Would you stop eating bread or drinking milk just because it was invented long ago?    Just because IBM has failed to nurture the academic work so no students uses their platforms, does not mean they are outdated or not the most powerful solution for a given problem.  Modern mailframes are incredibly powerful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A facetious response is to point out [Betteridge's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betteridge%27s_law_of_headlines), i.e. the answer to your question is "no".

There is nothing fundamentally different about COBOL and/or other legacy systems that prevents newcomers from learning them. That they're weird and unfamiliar and thus more effort than usual to learn is not a barrier, since bleeding-edge stuff is also weird and unfamiliar yet plenty of people are more than happy to dive in.

The main thing "keeping a good C# / Java developer from working with these systems" is not technology. Places which are still running this stuff are often also stuck in the 1950s when it comes to hiring practices, salaries, and working conditions.

I note the fine words of Charles Stross when it comes to being approached to work on something that none of the existing staff is prepared to touch with a ten foot pole: ["I want eight thousand a day. Plus expenses."](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/7643769-so-you-open-your-mouth-and-listen-to-yourself-say) Follow the link to the full quote for the NSFW punchline.